# Making connection to Ubuntu Server at my home from another computer

Tags: networking

I set Ubuntu Server 14.04 at my desktop computer and configured static ip and everything works fine when i ping i got response.I'm able to connect to server throught putty and also from FilleZilla from my laptop running Windows 7.

But now i have a problem connecting from another computer (lets say from my work).The address of server is something like 192.168.1.21 and on my laptop is 192.168.1.13 so i'm able to connect because i'm in the same network.But how to connect from another computer thats not in same network?

Can somebody help me with that?I would be greatfull.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot connect to a local IP address from a computer outside the network. You need to connect to your public IP. Although you normally have all ports closed and depending on your router you may or may not be able to open them. By opening the necessary port and forwarding traffic to your local IP you will be able to connect to your server from work via your public IP.

**How to**:

This may or may not work for you, since different routers and different internet providers give you different features and some may not allow this at all. This is a method that work for me and should work similar for you.

1. Access your admin panel and open port 22 for incoming traffic (or whatever port you want to use).
2. Forward traffic from this port to you computer (your local IP).
3. Figure out your public IP, possibly from [this website](http://www.whatsmyip.org/).

You should now be able to connect to your computer via your public IP using PuTTY or other clients. You could also open more ports to for instance host your website on your computer, or alike.